# JsonView - define Default View

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jackson, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring boot (MVC, JPA) application and it is required to return different attributes on different requests. I found the @JsonView annotation and it seems to work. But do I need to annotate every attribute with a basic view?

Example:

**Entity1**

```
 @Entity
    public class Entity1 implements Serializable {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;

      @JsonView(JsonViews.ExtendedView.class)
      private String name;

      @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "entity1", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      List<Entity2> entities2;

      @JsonView(JsonView.ExtendedView.class)
      @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "entity1", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      List<Entity3> entities3;

    }
```

**Entity2**

```
@Entity
public class Entity2 implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;
}
```

**Entity3**

```
@Entity
public class Entity3 implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;
}
```

**Views**

```
public class JsonViews {
  public static class BasicView { }
  public static class ExtendedView extends BasicView { }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @JsonView(JsonViews.BasicView.class)
  public @ResponseBody List<Entity1> index() {

    return repositoryEntity1.findAll();

  }
```

This is a trimmed example but I think it applies to the problem. I expect that the controller returns the Ids and the list of `Entity2` objects. But it returns an empty object with "No Properties". If I annotate every attribute of every class involved in this request, it seems to work, but is this really needed or the best solution? Is there a way to define a "DefaultView"?

thanks

Edit: If I annotate the JpaRepository it returns the entire object including the list with Entity3 objects.

Comment: Yes you do need to add that to every variable

Comment: Please check your post.

Answer (score 16):

No, you do not need to define views on all properties. Insert

`spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion=true`

in your `application.properties`. This will cause properties without the `@JsonView` annotation to be included in the response and only the annotated properties will be filtered.

In your Controller, properties without a view or with the `BasicView` annotated will be returned.

Comment: When you annotate fields in object which is a field in another object without @JsonView annotations, the fields in the first one all will be included anyway.

Comment: @KenavR did the answer solved your question?